# MS SQL Server slow performance on high concurrency with Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, sql-server-2008-r2

im currently using MS SQL Server 2008 in my project.

We have done performance test on our solution and we found that the time taken to execute some queries became extremely slow.

Eg.
if there is only 1 transaction going into the system, the time taken to execute the select query is about 40ms.

if the concurrency is high, the time taken to execute the select query can take up to 30 seconds for the same query.

Is there anyway that we can tune the database or any sort?

This is the query that Hibernate generated.

```
SELECT . . . 
FROM TERMINAL this_ 
LEFT OUTER JOIN MERCHANT merchant2_ ON this_.MERCHANT_FK=merchant2_.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN MOBILE_USER mobileuser3_ ON this_.MOBILEUSER_FK=mobileuser3_.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN MERCHANT merchant4_ ON mobileuser3_.MERCHANT_FK=merchant4_.ID 
WHERE this_.MOBILEUSER_FK=7 AND this_.STATUS='ACTIVE' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Hi MarkD, im sorry for my ignorance for not knowing inside out for the workings of stackoverflow. I have always upvoted the answers but did not realise about the check mark.

Comment: This is the query that Hibernate generated.

SELECT 
.
.
.
FROM TERMINAL this_
LEFT OUTER JOIN MERCHANT merchant2_ ON this_.MERCHANT_FK=merchant2_.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN MOBILE_USER mobileuser3_ ON this_.MOBILEUSER_FK=mobileuser3_.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN MERCHANT merchant4_ ON mobileuser3_.MERCHANT_FK=merchant4_.ID
WHERE this_.MOBILEUSER_FK=7
  AND this_.STATUS='ACTIVE' LIMIT 1

Comment: I've edited your post to add the query. I was hoping to see something that would obviously cause contention. Lets see if someone comes up with any good ideas. Good luck!

Comment: `LIMIT 1` in SQL Server 2008 R2? I'd expect to see that syntax if you were connecting to MySQL. Which would explain the poor performance.

Comment: Why would connecting to mysql explain the poor performance?

Answer (score -1):

This may be faster if you do not have so much data in the tables;

```
SELECT . . . 
FROM TERMINAL this_ 
LEFT OUTER JOIN MOBILE_USER mobileuser3_ ON this_.MOBILEUSER_FK=mobileuser3_.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN MERCHANT merchant4_ ON mobileuser3_.MERCHANT_FK=merchant4_.ID 
WHERE this_.MOBILEUSER_FK=7 AND this_.STATUS='ACTIVE' and 
this_.MERCHANT_FK in (SELECT merchant2_.ID FROM MERCHANT merchant2_)
```

Comment: -1 OP is using an ORM, so it generates the SQL for him. Specialising somewhat defeats the purpose of an ORM. Also `LIMIT` is not valid for SQL Server.

Comment: you should check his first post. The generated query has limit. We do not know currently how the Query is generated and under which conditions.

I am also aware that Limit is a condition for MYSQL and does not exist within MSSQL...

Comment: dear all, i generated the query when i am connecting to a MySQL Db. but the same query is used for MSSQL 2008 R2 server that we have for production. (without the LIMIT). I have used the MSSQL Server profiler tool to profile the queries and found that they are execution time is fast. the queries finish in milliseconds. im suspecting might be an issue with the connection pool now.